# How to map a Map?

Tags: dart

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'abc': 'abc'
};

map.entries.map((f){
  print(f);
});

List.from(map.entries).map((f){
  print(f);
});
```

Did not print any words! Why?

Comment: @Ma Mars I haven't seen it at first, but the end of your question contained some "weird" text that I understand upset some people and caused them to vote for close and downvoted. StackOverflow questions are not only for the one who asks them, but to build a knowledge base for future visitors who run into similar problems. This is why the community is picky about the quality of questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` (like several other methods on iterables) is lazy. It only executes when the result is iterated.

You can use `.toList()` to get the lazy methods executed:

```
  map.entries.map((f) {
    print(f);
  }).toList();
```

or

```
  var result = map.entries.map((f) {
    print(f);
    return '${f.key} - ${f.value}';
  });

  for(final item in result) {
    print(item);
  }
```

Comment: tanks ,you are right

Comment: Actually for your example `forEach()` would be a better fit than `map()`. `forEach()` also causes lazy methods to be executed and would be a combination of `map()` and `toList()` for your example.